# What does "User agent string" and "Document mode" exactly do?

Tags: internet-explorer

I am a bit confused about IE dev tools, IE 11 has  "User agent string" and "Document mode" while IE 9 had "Document mode" and "Browser mode".Suppose I want to test my webpage using these tools for how my page looks in IE 7 so what do I need to set from the two available settings? I am looking for detailed yet simple explanation...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Briefly:

- Browser mode controls the user-agent string IE reports to a webserver.  This helps some sites display because those sites expect a certain value of IE and only deliver content when their expectations have been met.
- Document mode controls how IE interprets are renders [content from a website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx).  For best results, you [want edge mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn384051(v=vs.85).aspx), which is the highest mode supported by any recent version of IE. By highest supported mode, I mean IE9 displays content in IE9 standards mode, IE10 displays content in IE10 standards mode, and so on.  (You can't very well expect IE9 to support IE10 standards mode.
- You can use the F12 tools to display pages in other document modes be using the emulation tab or the controls to the right hand side of the F12 tools toolbar display area.

Alternatively, you can also use the [VM images available](https://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools) from modern.ie to actually test your site in those versions.

In general, you should not depend on the version of any given browser, but should rather use beter practices like [feature detection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh273397(v=vs.85).aspx), [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement), [graceful fallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh273396(v=vs.85).aspx), and so on.

For more details (and more links to various details), take a look at [Specifying legacy document modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx) or some of the other answers I've been posting recently.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance